# PHP - Проверка ссылки https://vk.com/?w=wall

Tags: php

требуется проверить ссылку в формате (https://vk.com/id542266014?w=wall542266014_3), конкретней, обязательные слова в данной ссылке - https://vk.com/?w=wall_
И так, % - символ ненадобности(символы, которые проверять не нужно, они могут быть разными). https://vk.com/%?w=%_%

Answer (score 0):

Для подобного рода манипуляциями со строкой удобно использовать регулярные выражения.

[Регулярные выражения (шаблоны)](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=regexp&page=008)

[Синтаксис регулярных выражений](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)